# What does "all" in "with all this noise going on" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ## for all
>
> despite
>
> - For **all** its clarity of style, the book is not easy reading.

[Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/all_1#all_idmg_29)

> ## with
>
> 14. because of a situation that exists
>
> - With John away there’s more room in the house.
> - I can’t do my homework with ***all*** this noise going on.

[Source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with)

---

The "**all**" in "For **all** its clarity of style" emphasizes that the style is very clear.
I wonder what the "***all***" in "with ***all*** this noise going on" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example, 'all' means that there is a lot (in this case  of noise).

So:

*"I don't feel comfortable with **all** these people watching"*

Means that the speaker feels that there are a lot (too many) people watching for them to feel comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

In the second sentence, "all" indicates that there's a lot of noise, and it's the *amount of noise* that's the problem.

Without "all", it sounds as if there's something in the nature of the noise itself that's the problem --like how distracting or irritating that particular noise is-- rather than how loud the noise is.

> I can’t do my homework with this noise going on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question. It seems to me that the use of the "all" in "with all this noise going on" doesn't matches any of the senses of "all" in the oxfordlearnersdictionary. (www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com) I wonder about the reason.

Comment: The definition here is closest to "the whole amount of". Consider: "*I can't do my homework with **the whole amount of** this noise going on.*" It's a bit wordy, but the meaning is correct.

Comment: I wonder which sense of the entry for "all" at www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com fits the use of the "**all**" in "For **all** its clarity of style".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss Have you checked a good dictionary like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all)

Comment: It seems to me that sense 6a of adjective "all" fits the "**all**" in "For **all** its clarity of style". I wonder what you think about that.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss I don't think so. "All" cannot modify the pronoun "it" as an adjective. Search the page for "for all" to find my choice.

Comment: It seems to me that any of senses of "all" doesn't fit the "**all**" in "For **all** its clarity of style"  I think "For all" is an idiom.  I wonder what you think about these.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss I think it's the same as *pronoun 1 b : used ... to indicate a lack of knowledge, interest, or effectiveness*. It means, even though the book has very clear style, it is not easy to read. In other words, the clear style *wasn't effective* in making the book easy to read.